# Issue when creating a Producer Config to an Existing Consumer Service Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a Springboot service which successfully consumes a message from kafka topic. As part of further development I have a requirement to publish the message to another kafka topic in same consumer service which was created before and running fine. But when I introduce a Kafka producer Config it gives me error in consumer config saying

```
 WARN  | [main] | org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh | Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaConsumerService' defined in file 
 [C:\Workspaces\springboot\test-app\target\classes\com\testapp\execution\carrier\km\consumer\KafkaConsumerService.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaListenerContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/testapp/execution/carrier/km/config/KafkaConsumerConfig.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'kafkaListenerContainerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate<java.lang.String, com.testapp.execution.carrier.km.model.CarrierStopEBO>' 
available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}


Description:

Parameter 0 of method kafkaListenerContainerFactory in com.testapp.execution.carrier.km.config.KafkaConsumerConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'kafkaTemplate' in 'KafkaAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate' kafkaTemplatetest


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate' in your configuration.
```

my working kafka consumer config which is suddenly throwing issues after introducing producer config

KafkaConsumerConfig.java

```
@Slf4j
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
    @Value("${spring.kafka.offset-reset-policy}")
    private String offsetResetPolicy;
    @Value("${spring.kafka.group-id}")
    private String groupId;
    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.max-poll-interval}")
    private Integer maxPollInterval;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.max-poll-records}")
    private Integer maxPollRecords;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.session-timeout}")
    private Integer sessionTimeout;
    @Value("${spring.kafka.trusted-packages}")
    private String trustedPacakges;

    public KafkaConsumerConfig() {
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {

        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, offsetResetPolicy);
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, trustedPacakges);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, maxPollRecords);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, maxPollInterval);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, sessionTimeout);//
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, SASL_PLAINTEXT);

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, CarrierStopEBO> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),
                new ErrorHandlingDeserializer2<>(new JsonDeserializer<>(carrierStopEBO.class, false)));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, CarrierStopEBO> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            KafkaTemplate<String, CarrierStopEBO> kafkaTemplate1) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, CarrierStopEBO> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.setAckDiscarded(true);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAuthorizationExceptionRetryInterval(Duration.ofMillis(30000));
  

        return factory;
    }


}
```

The Producer config which after adding it to the service causing issue

KafkaProducerConfig .java

```
@Slf4j
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Value("${sni.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${sni.kafka.producer.properties.security.protocol}")
    private String securityProtocol;

    @Value("${sni.kafka.producer.properties.sasl.mechanism}")
    private String saslMechanism;

    @Value("${sni.kafka.producer.properties.sasl.jaas.config}")
    private String jaasConfig;

    public KafkaProducerConfig() {
   }
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, CarrierModelDTO> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, DefaultPartitioner.class);
        configProperties.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, securityProtocol);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, CarrierModelDTO>(configProperties);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, CarrierModelDTO> kafkaTemplatetest() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<String, CarrierModelDTO>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

I was able to figure out there is some clash between consumer and producer config with the producer config code below

```
 @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, CarrierModelDTO> kafkaTemplatetest() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<String, CarrierModelDTO>(producerFactory());
    }
```

Can someone advice on the issue

Comment: Typo? `CarrierStopEBO` is mentioned in the error, but `carrierStopEBO.class` is in the code... Everywhere wlse uses `CarrierModelDTO`

Comment: sorry its a typo

Comment: Okay, so the error says you have no `@Bean public KafkaTemplate` in your consumer config, which is true

Comment: correct, If i delete the producer config from my project. it works but if i include producer config, the consumer config expects that KafkaTemplate. Kind of Odd behaviour or am i missing something

Comment: The error says `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` bean accepts a `KafkaTemplate` bean named `kafkaTemplate1`. You can use `@Qualifier` to set this name on a method or you need a method named that that returns a `KafkaTemplate` instance as a bean

Comment: That `kafkaTemplate1` is not used in the `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` bean definition.

Comment: what does that mean , i have used that in ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory

Answer (score 0):

You expect a `KafkaTemplate<String, CarrierStopEBO>`, but your bean is `KafkaTemplate<String, CarrierModelDTO>`. Please, revise your types . On the other hand your current code doesn’t seem use that template at all…

Comment: How can i define KafkaTemplate in Consumer config. The point here is consumer config clashes with the producer config KafkaTemplate

Comment: Why do you need to specify a `KafkaTemplate` in the container factory?

Comment: For Error handling stuffs like DLQ, I need the KafkaTemplate for consumer

Comment: Right, so what is the problem to define an appropriate `KafkaTemplate`? The current one you show has different generic argument, do probably you need it for something else therefore it is irrelevant to the current context of the question and misleading